# Regular expression for get all tags that contain the attribute (href|src)

Tags: php, html, regex, string, tags

This doesn't work.  Can anybody spot why?

```
"/<(.*)[href|src](.*)>/ismU"
```

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: People are crazy for downvoting this. I asked a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063441/regex-to-replace-regex-to-replace-html-questions and they deleted it even though the question had over 10 upvotes. Now because they deleted it, I don't know how to not see questions like this on SO.

Comment: Can you tell us what it's actually supposed to do, first?

Comment: Banning regex questions outright would prevent this type of question, but as with anything involving regexes, now there's two problems...

Comment: Reopen. Let's finish it once and for all. We need a way to make such questions as sticky. So that no one will have to ask again.

Comment: @manojlds, that deleted question totally belongs over on meta, though I expect it might also get closed there.  Sigh.

Comment: @Charles - don't take me seriously. Yeah maybe on meta but not in that form. I meant for it to be on SO. Going to post on meta - something like whenever someone types regex and html in the question, the obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 is mentioned and the person is warned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several things:

`(.*)` will match across tag boundaries if it has to (even though you did use the `/U` modifier to make quantifiers lazy by default.

`[href|src]` means "match one character, either a `h`, a `r`, an `e`, an `f`, a `|`, an `s` or a `c`".

The `/m` modifier is useless if you don't use `^` or `$` anchors in your regex.

Try this instead:

```
/<[^<>]*(href|src)[^<>]*>/i
```

But even with this, applying regular expressions to HTML is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you for answering this (admittedly bad) question in a calm and helpful way. The communities unhelpful standard response to these regex/html questions makes me sad sometimes.

Comment: @Jens: The question didn't explain what results they were expecting or in what way it wasn't working. It wasn't an actual question, any more than posting 1000 lines of code and saying "My code doesn't work. How can I fix it?" would be a real question. That being said, @Tim's answer was well written, especially the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve your problem using [XPaths](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) instead of regexes.